# In what context is the word Bhavin(भाविन) used in Hindu scriptures?

Tags: name, sanskrit

I would like to know if the Sanskrit word Bhavin(भाविन)is mentioned in Hindu scriptures and in what context is it used?

Comment: https://www.sanskritdictionary.com/scans/?col=1&img=mw0749.jpg (see the last column)..

Comment: Thank you for your response....Does the word have any Divine connotations?...The dictionary says the meaning of the word is ‘living/being’....Does this in any way mean ‘Ever-living’ or ‘Ever-being’?

Comment: Is it [Bhāvin](https://www.sanskritdictionary.com/?iencoding=hk&q=bhAvin&lang=sans&action=Search) (भाविन्) or [Bhavin](https://www.sanskritdictionary.com/?iencoding=hk&q=bhavin&lang=sans&action=Search) (भविन्)? There is no such word as Bhaveen (भवीन्) in Sanskrit...maybe you should change your name to Bhavin :)

Comment: Word Bhavin is used in many ways throughout different texts even we find its use in Mahabharata. I will post the answer  If the question  gets opened.

Comment: Avoid sharing your e-mail address here. You can click on the reopen button so the question can be reopened. But you need to clarify if you're looking for भाविन्, भविन् or भवीन् - as they are all different words. You can edit and clarify.

Comment: Looking for भाविन।Could you tell me how to reopen the question?...

Comment: Sorry, your need [at least 250 reputation](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes) to see the reopen button. For now, you can flag the mods (click on flag icon and select 'moderator intervention') to reopen or [ask on meta](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com) on why your Qn should be reopened.